# What does these extra arguments mean?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

What does these extra arguments mean, like in here

```
int data[num];
vector<int> v;
// ...
v.insert(v.begin(),data, data+num);
```

Why are there more than 2 arguments? Please explain the functioning in detail.

Comment: Read the Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: @Nim: Much nicer way to put it than what I was just writing.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) that takes a position in that vector and a range of elements to insert before that position:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
template< class InputIt >
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

In your case, you are inserting the entire contents from the `data` array at the beginning of the vector (`data` decays to a pointer to the first element and `data + num` points one past the end of the array).